# Change FXFlex breakpoint values

Tags: angular8, angular-flex-layout

Is there a possibility to change and use the FxFlex default breakpoint values without defining a custom breakpoint provider?

I would like to change the breakpoint media query for aliases sm and md. From

```
sm  'screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 959px)'
md  'screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1279px)'
```

to something like

```
sm  'screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px)'
md  'screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1279px)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
For example to change the XL breakpoint from 1920px to 1600px, add this code in your app.module.ts :

```
import { DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS } from "@angular/flex-layout";

DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS.find(item => item.alias == "lg").mediaQuery = "screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1599.98px)";
DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS.find(item => item.alias == "xl").mediaQuery = "screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 4999.98px)";
DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS.find(item => item.alias == "lt-xl").mediaQuery = "screen and (max-width: 1599.98px)";
DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS.find(item => item.alias == "gt-lg").mediaQuery = "screen and (min-width: 1600px)";
```

Answer (score -1):

In `node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/__ivy_ngcc__\esm2015` is a file called 'core.js', in that file are a const called 'DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS', in this const are defined the default breakpoints, you can change his values, but I don't know if it's safe to do it, and I assume that you will have to change it every time you update the package.

Also there is the same const (or var in some cases) in the files:

```
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm2015/core.js
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm5/core.es5.js
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/bundles/flex-layout-core.umd.js
```

Note that each file has its own map that refers to the breakpoint variables, you may have to change the map of the files you change

I hope this can help you